Interface "Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection" not found
I get "Interface "Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection" not found"
My export.php in App\Exports;
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Response;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class Export implements FromCollection
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return Response::all();
    }
}

My composer.json
"require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.31",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^1.1"
    },

